# Asynchronous Tasks in Java Web app

Tags: java, asynchronous, quartz-scheduler

Asynchronous jobs such as download scores from the website, or send emails after completion of some critical tasks.
Rightnow we when we download some scores, we have to wait on the current page to get the response page or to get file downloaded.
Is there a possibility that i can click on download scores and it happens in the background so that i can navigate to other parts
of the website, and in the mean-time check the status of the job. Or Schedule some job later in the future and get its execution results
via email.

Ours is a struts 2 webapplication with Hibernate 3.5 ORM. After browsing into some java scheduling libraries, got some info on Quartz. 
But is Quartz the right library for the above requirements or any other library that i can try for? 
Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need some sort of asynchronous processing support. You can use:

- [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) - this library is very comprehensive and allows you to schedule all sorts of jobs. If you want to use it *only* for the purpose of scheduling jobs in the background and run them immediately, might be an overkill
- use thread pool, see [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class
- [jms](/questions/tagged/jms) queue can listen on requests and process them asynchronously in [mdb](/questions/tagged/mdb)s
- Finally you can take advantage of `@Async`/`@Asynchronous` support in [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) or [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb)

Then you mut somehow restore the results. Depening on whether you want to deliver them directly in the browser or via e-mail:

- every time you are rendering a page, check whether there aren't any completed/in progress jobs. If there are some completed jobs, display an extra link on the page somewhere (sort of notification). If the job is in progress, start an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request and ask every other second or use long-polling/[comet](/questions/tagged/comet) to receive the result immediately
- if you want to send results by e-mail, just send it after the job finishes. Much simpler but less user-friendly IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response. As mentioned about Quart-Scheduler, the library is about running a scheduled job in the background, does it allow to  run a job with user interaction( button click or link) kind off?   also is Threadpool (executors) is an alternative solution?

Comment: What do you mean by running a job with user interaction? You can start a job on user action, like button click, but then the job runs in background and you have no control over it. Quartz uses thread pool underneath so if you need something lightweight, use thread pool directly.

Comment: So using thread pool directly will be enough to add jobs and execute in background, and get the jobs status intermediately. And send emails / or a popup on the site after job completion.

Comment: @SangramAnand: if that was a question, then yes. You will however need some mechanism to restore job status. Shared memory, callbacks, `Future`. The same applies to Quartz.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try implementing based on your guidelines.

Comment: @SangramAnand: don't hesitate to post follow-up questions if you encounter some issues.

Comment: put the thoughts into action in the code.. but i doubt whether am on the right track.. please find the code in the below link in your free time..  https://gist.github.com/c303d1cbef8f164e9b69

Answer (score 1):

Quartz is certainly one way to do that - and works well if you want to schedule a job to run at a particular time or with a particular frequency.

If you just want to kick something off in the background in response to a user action, and check its status, there are a few other ways to do it which may be better suited to this pattern:

- the java.util.concurrent package: you can set up a ThreadPoolExecutor and submit tasks to it that implement `Callable`.  You get back a `Future<T>` object that you can check for completion (`isDone`) and get its result when complete (`get`).
- with EJB or Spring, there is also a concept of a (session) bean method being `@Async` or `@Asynchronous`, which return a `Future<T>` as well and behave as above.  Basically this just abstracts away the thread-pool creation and management from your code, and moves it into the container or framework.