# Threads in JSF?

Tags: multithreading, jsf, jakarta-ee

I new in JSF, and I need use Threads for google maps. I am using primefaces for google maps, but I need excute a thread in background to get lat and long from data base and then graphic the markers in the map.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not specific to JSF, but rather to web applications in general. So, how to perform tasks asynchronously in a Java web applications? Definitely NOT by creating your own threads.

A Java web application runs in an application server (for example jBoss). It is the responsibility of the application server to manage Java threads for you. For instance, it will use a separate thread for each web request that comes in. The application server creates a pool of threads and reuses those threads since it is somewhat expensive to create new ones all the time. That's why you should not create your own, especially if it's done for every web request since it will directly impact scalability.

In order to execute tasks asynchronously, you can use the ejb @Asynchronous annotation (assuming the app is running in a Java EE container like jBoss, but not Tomcat).

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class AsyncBean {

    @Asynchronous
    public void doSomethingAsynchronously() {
       // when this EJB is injected somewhere, and this method is called, it will return to the caller immediately and its logic will run in the background
    }

}
```

If the app is not running in a Java EE container, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932983/asynchronous-tasks-in-java-web-app) which nicely lays out some other options for async processing in web apps.

Answer (score 2):

JSF is **completely unrelated** to your problem. For this case, JSF will act as mere HTML generator. Your specific problem is how to prepare data asynchronously and consume it from your web app.

You can create the thread manually when the application starts on a class that implements `ServletContextListener` interface, like this:

```
public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    ExecutorService executor;

    public ApplicationListener() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //process the data here...
            }
        }
        executor.submit(task);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Improve the design above to fulfill your requirements. Take into account that creating threads in an application server should only be done **if you know what you're doing**.

Another implementation would be to use another application to do the processing (let's call it Data Processor), which by default will run on a separate thread and environment. Then, communicate your web application with this Data Processor through a cache or nosql application like EhCache, Infinispan or Hazelcast.